# How to groupby with strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've been trying to solve an issue I've posted about before. Right now I have a df and I want to add numbers to the `Pairing` as long as the `type` and `Name` match. I was somewhat successful using the groupby method like so:

```
x = df['type'].str[:5]
df['Pairing'] = df.groupby([x, 'Name']).ngroup()+1


Name    | type  |      Pairing 
---------------------------
Charles |Circle       | 1
Scott   |Square       | 2
Scott   |Triangle     | 3
Anne    |Rectangle    | 4
Anne    |Rectangle2   | 4
Anne    |Oval         | 5
Anne    |Oval         | 5
Bart    |Octagon      | 6
```

I use `.str[:5]` because sometimes a number or symbol will be attached to one `type` and not the other. this method works, however if I have a type like  `Oval` it wont work because its less that 5.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. If anyone has any suggestions please let me know! I'm wondering if and `if` statement might work here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to eliminate leading spaces with `strip`:

```
x = df['type'].str.strip().str[:5]
```

Or use `extract` to eliminate all non-alpha character like this:

```
x = df['type'].str.extract('^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)')[0].str[:5]
```

Comment: Woh, I think this worked! I have to do a little more vetting but it looks like it worked. Thanks so much. I'm new to coding and python and I'd love to understand what is happening in this line ```('^[^a-zA-Z]*([a-zA-Z]+)')``` if you have a min to explain

Comment: @Rockey Try [regex.com](https://regex101.com/r/CJr8PR/1).

Answer (score 1):

This will remove the numbers:

```
x = df['type'].str.replace('\d+', '')
```

Comment: hmm, I don't particularly want to remove the numbers, I'd like the ```type``` with str less that 5 to get grouped properly

Comment: Then create a new column:
df['type_abc']= df['type'].str.replace('\d+', '')